# While connecting to localhost even though if we give wrong password , will the connection exist?

Tags: php, database, database-connection

This is my code , actual password is null..

i.e  $password = "" ; instead of this i gave some random characters and to my surprise connection was existed.. How is this possible ? Can anyone guide me please....

```
class Database
{
    public $server = "localhost";
    public $user = "root";
    public $password = "qqqq";
    public $database_name = "sample";
    public $database_connection = "";
    public $class_name = __CLASS__;
    public $function_name = "";
    private $table_name     = "";


    //constructor
    public function __construct(){
    //establishes connection to database
        $this->database_connection = new mysqli($this->server, $this->user, $this->password, $this->database_name);
        if($this->database_connection->connect_error)
            die ("Connection failed".$this->database_connection->connect_error);
    }

    //destructor
    public function __destruct(){
        $this->database_connection = null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer for my question... 
Its since i declared $password as public i was able to access since re declared $password in child class as null. Hence i change the access specifier to private and its working perfectly as per my needs..

Even though i didn't get any response for my que am happy that my que had dozen views.... Thanks to them